# Flot won't Plot (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flot

I'm playing around with FLOT with Ruby and I'm having a hard time passing the code to javascript; I know my javascript isn't reading the data correctly from Ruby.  I need some syntax help.

```
o={};
o= {'label' => "A", 'data' => @example.collect{|x| [Time.utc(x.date).to_i, x.num]}}
render :text => o.to_json
```

I have successfully rendered the output as such:

{"label":"A","data":[[1281225600,1.31],[1281225600,1.31],[1281225600,1.25]]}

The HTML outputs this data only.

My javascript is as follows:

```
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(text);
    var options = {
    lines: { show: true },
    points: { show: true },
    xaxis: { mode: "time",  timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",   minTickSize: [1, "day"]}
    };  

       var data = obj;            
      $.plot(placeholder,[data],options);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that Ruby puts out timestamps in the Unix format (i.e. **seconds** since the epoch `1281225600`).  Flot requires javascript timestamps, which count the **milliseconds** since the epoch, i.e. `1281225600*1000`.

So in your Ruby code, your best bet is to do something like this:

```
o={};
o= {'label' => "A", 'data' => @example.collect{|x| [Time.utc(x.date).to_i*1000, x.num]}}
render :text => o.to_json
```

Or if you prefer, you could loop over the obj.data and do the multiplication on the Javascript side:

```
for (i=0;i<obj.data.length;i++){
    obj.data[i] = obj.data[i]*1000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the Unix time format isn't the problem.  If you do the math it works.  It's the parameter passing that's the problem.    Possibly the jQuery.parseJSON(text) portion.

Comment: Post a copy of your JSON text then, so I can take a look.  FWIW though, the data you posted in your example does **not** work in flot.  It may plot something, but I doubt it's what you want.

Comment: Hmmm.. are you saying that my rendered output is bad? is that why Flot doesn't render it?
my ruby and my java text is the way i wrote it in the top example.

Comment: oh yea disregard the timestamp.  i'm working with a large dataset here so the dates are quite insignificant.

Comment: Oh, so when you say you "successfully rendered the output", you mean that `{"label":"A","data":[[1281225600,1.31],[1281225600,1.31],[1281225600,1.25]]}` is what Ruby outputs?  Or are you saying that with that data object, flot renders a graph correctly?

Comment: With your given data, I multiplied the timestamps by 1000 and modified them to not all be the same, and I get a perfectly fine graph:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/jtakk/

Comment: my html doesn't output anything... it only outputs the data "{"label":"A","data":[[1281225600,1.31],[1281225600,1.31],[1281225600,1.25]]}" literally.  just plain text.
The js portion doesn't pick up the code or something and doesn't work at all.

Comment: i feel like im getting close:
`$.post("/index/graph", options, function (text) {
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(text);
   var options = {
        lines: { show: true },
        points: { show: true },
        xaxis: { mode: "time",  timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",   minTickSize: [1, "day"]}}; 
  var data = obj;
 $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
 };`

Comment: Seems like you're getting close, yeah.  you can skip the `jQuery.parseJSON` too if you tell `$.post` that the results will be json (specify your `dataType` as json when doing the post).

Comment: yea now for some reason i get a popup that says:
which is a: application/json
from: http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it....

Ruby code:

```
    @o={};
    @o= {'label' => "A", 'data' => @example.collect{|x| [Time.utc(x.date).to_i, x.num]}}
```

Java code:

```
$(function () {

var obj = <%= @o.to_json %>;
var options = {
   lines: { show: true },
   points: { show: true },
   xaxis: { mode: "time",  timeformat: "%m/%d/%y",   minTickSize: [1, "day"]}
};  

var data = obj;            
$.plot(placeholder,[data],options);
});
```

Comment: Now my Ruby and Javascript are making love!!